# Compiling Qt 5.13 for 32 bit environment under Linux

Tags: linux, qt, 32-bit

There is no 32 bit version of Qt 5.13 available for linux, but I need it for one of my applications. I've performed all tasks to compile and build 32 bit version. It builds fine, but is missing "Src" folder under "/opt/Qt5.13/5.13", which I need to buil my application. How to generate the "Src" folder with all the includes and source code stuff?

Comment: with the `cp -r` command?

Comment: What do you expect it to contain? Qt's source code? Why do you need that to build your application?

Comment: I need header files mostly and code structure that is provided by standard Qt installer. My problem is that multiple header files are missing in normal source, like mysql headers. Everything is ok when I use Qt 5.5 from installer downloaded from Qt site